# Eclipse EObject proxy resolution, without a running Eclipse instance

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf

I have the following problem/scenario. I'm using an emf based object XML model called Artop, and I want to use it in a non-Eclipse based Java application.

For most things this is working fine, I can create/save/read a model. The problem comes when an XML model is read when it contains a reference from another part of the XML model, this in the EMF EObject tree becomes a proxy. And when I try to save the resource again, this proxy cannot be resolved and it causes a crash of the whole program.

My question is simple, does anyone know how to resolve proxy EObjects without an Eclipse instance running? (I know the file the EObject is located in.)

Or even better, has anyone used Artop outside of an Eclipse environment?

Comment: There should not be any problems to load cross-resource references outside of Eclipse. One thing that might cause problems is if the reference URI:s are of the wrong type. For example: Inside Eclipse the `platform:` URI scheme can be used, but not outside Eclipse. Can you edit your question and add information about what the cross-resource URI:s in your files look like?